# Incorrect Ruble-symbol on Invoice PDF prestashop 1.6 not showing properly

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, prestashop-1.6

Using Prestashop 1.6 - and on the PDF's (Invoice & delivery) the Russian Ruble symbol won't render properly, converts to a "square".  It is working without problem on all other areas of our site.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is linked to the font include in TCPDF, i think the font use for your iso code not include this symbole.

The font folder for TCPDF is :

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.6/tools/tcpdf/fonts

**How to found the font use by TCPDF?**

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.6/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php

In this file you can know what font use for your country iso code

The font use depend to country iso code, so for RU the font is freeserif.
So the font freeserif not include Rouble.

**Solution?**

**Solution 1**

The easy solution is to change in the https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.6/classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php the font for your iso code by (dejavusans, cid0jp, ..) depending font in the folder tools/tcpdf/fonts.

**Solution 2**

The second solution, is to download TTF file who include the symbol(example you can search/download a font in http://www.dafont.com/) and generate a valid file with online converter
http://fonts.snm-portal.com/ (it is a first result for my search in google)

After you upload the file(s) generated in folder tools/tcpdf/fonts and edit the file PDFGenerator.php to point to your new font.

Comment: Hello, I would like to try solution 1, but I couldn't see the problem (apologies for the delay to respond).  In my /PDFGenerator.php file,  it correctly says  'ru' => 'freeserif', and in my /tools/tcpdf/fonts folder the freeserif.php file is also there.  But I am not clear what I need to change.  Please could you kindly explain.  Much thanks, Cynthia

Comment: It is just the font 'freeserif' not include rouble symbol, can you change by other font, such as dejavusans?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - unfortunately dejavusans also didn't work.

Comment: Can you test with other font you have in https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.6/tools/tcpdf/fonts?

Comment: hi, yes I tested with several others, but no change in result.